# How does a server process multiple API requests at same time?

Tags: html, multithreading, api, concurrency, process

Given the following situation:

1. Server receives API request from client A.
2. Server starts processing API request
3. Server receives API request from client B.
4. (What happens here?)

What happens in step 4?

My understanding is that, since the server is busy processing the first request, it won't even respond to the second request. To expand: I am picturing the application idle waiting for a request, but when it receives the first request (from client A), the application starts processing it and therefore is unable to even receive the second request.

I am assuming this is incorrect, but if someone can provide a detailed explanation of what happens in this situation, that would be very enlightening.

Comment: You already tagged your question with “multithreading”, so you should already know where your picture describing a purely single threaded point of view is wrong. There is nothing special to a server here, just recall (or reread) [what Multithreading is all about](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)).

Comment: Yes, but I would like a description of how these multiple threads all work together to process multiple API requests. And I want to see the correct terminology in action. For example, is it accurate to say the first thread "monitors a port", waiting for the next incoming request? And what are the implementation details of that "port monitoring"? And when the thread receives a request the thread starts processing that request and a second thread starts "monitoring the port"? And can multiple "threads" monitor a single "port" at a time? etc.

Comment: That’s too many questions at once. There are entire books about these topics. A server creates a *server socket* and calls a system function, typically called `accept`. The result of this operation is a new socket being connected to a particular client. This socket is typically handed over to a new thread processing this particular client’s request without any interference with the initial thread or other threads processing other clients. Ask the search engine of your choice for `server accept loop` and I’m sure, you’ll find examples.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for these details and for pointing me in the direction of server accept loops! I found one relevant article here: https://cs.smu.ca/~porter/csc/465/notes/net/servers.html that seems to answer many of the questions I have.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.